# Does this "Gender Decoder" have any basis?

Tags: job-listing

I am writing an ad for a data analyst position and my HR is telling me to use this site:

http://gender-decoder.katmatfield.com/

This strikes me as very sexist, basically saying that women cannot be described as leaders and that the wording needs to be softened so as to be able to appeal to women. The site says it bases all of its classification from one study. From reading the study, it seemed to me the researchers were confusing correlation with causation. The amount of female or male applicants is highly dependent on how many of each group are even interested in the first place.  I don't think professional applicants put much stock into the wording as much as what the job entails and whether or not they are qualified. They have likely put many years of training and education towards their career of choice. The amount of women engineers or other male dominated field is a different discussion and begins long before anyone is looking at a job listing.

A look at a [blog post](https://www.ere.net/you-dont-know-it-but-women-see-gender-bias-in-your-job-postings/) on the subject finds this example:

> Engineer Responsibilities:
>
> Feminine: Provide general support to project team in a manner
> complimentary to the company. Help clients with construction
> activities.
>
> Masculine: Direct project groups to manage project
> progress and ensure accurate task control. Determine compliance with
> client’s objectives.

These don't even mean the same thing, one implies a support role, and the other implies a managerial role.

I have put the question to women in my life, and received the same conclusion, it was sexist and insulting. I'd like to put the question to a broader group: Is this a valid concern that can be addressed by choosing more neutrally gender coded words, or is the study flawed and in of itself sexist against women?

Comment: Are you asking if your HR are sexist? The site itself matters little, it's just trying to sell a product or follow an agenda.

Comment: No, I am sure that HR has good intentions, but if I am to disregard the findings of the decoder, then I would like more than just my own intuition and bias as reasoning. Thanks.

Comment: Is correlation and causation not irrelevant here? Like does it matter whether more women act a certain way *because* they are women or that this behaviour for other reasons appears more often in women?

Comment: Are you trying to recruit a candidate who is qualified for the data analyst position, will fit in well with your department and company culture, and prove to be an asset in the long run (who might happen to be a woman); or are you trying to recruit a woman (who might happen to be a valuable employee)?

Comment: the title question "Does decoder has any basis" is not the same as the core question "Is this a valid concern that can be addressed..."

Comment: @Helena do a job search for "submissive." I found not one position in Canada using that word.

Comment: Unless this question is rewritten to ask "how can I address my concerns about sexism in our recruitment process", I'd submit it would be better on Skeptics or even Statistics. In the current form it's basically asking "is this study valid?", which isn't a workplace question at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes there is a basis,  if you assume that job descriptions are not meaningfully accurate.**

[LinkedIn did a research report](https://business.linkedin.com/content/dam/me/business/en-us/talent-solutions-lodestone/body/pdf/Gender-Insights-Report.pdf) that found that women are less likely to apply for a job if it is more senior than their own. So by reducing the apparent seniority of a position, plausibly you could attract more female applicants. The example you cites reduces the seniority of the duties, so that might be why it works. HBR has an article about [how men are far less likely than women to self select out of the hiring process](https://hbr.org/2014/08/why-women-dont-apply-for-jobs-unless-theyre-100-qualified) for fearing to be under qualified.

As a guy I agree, those are nowhere near the same job. But job descriptions are often hilariously meaningless anyway. In my last job, test driven development was emphasized. When they replaced me, the post continued to emphasize test driven development. For months, the test runner was broken, so the existing tests were not even being run. They do not do anything close to TDD. The job description for my current job was less meaningless, but they still required experience for technologies that we do not use. In every job I have ever held, the description has differed wildly from the day to day, even if just in the tools used.

So if women self select out because a position seems to senior and job descriptions are relatively inaccurate anyway, with the only goal being to convey a general sense of what the job is, I can see the decoder being useful for recruiting women.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend that you post two ads— one that you and HR agree is accurate, but suffers from HR's criticism, and one that includes HR's adjustment process. For your purposes, treat the applicant pools together. Later, have a meeting to evaluate your and HR's opinions by comparing the separate pools. That way, you and HR get what each wants, you are being a team player, and you'll have an interesting experiment.